# Why Username and Password not accepted when I send mail in php?

Tags: php, sendmail, phpmailer

Hi this is my problem:

I want send a mail and this is my mail code:

```
<?php

require "vendor/autoload.php";

class HelperMail{

  private $oPhpMailer;


    function __construct(){

        $this->oPhpMailer = new PHPMailer();
        $this->oPhpMailer->isSMTP();
        $this->oPhpMailer->SMTPDebug = 2;
        $this->oPhpMailer->Debugoutput = 'html';
        $this->oPhpMailer->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
        $this->oPhpMailer->SMTPAuth = true;

    }
            public function mailFrom($from,$usuario){
              $this->oPhpMailer->setFrom($from,$usuario);             
            }
            public function mailPort($puerto){
              $this->oPhpMailer->Port = $puerto;   
            }
            public function mailUsuario($usuario){
              $this->oPhpMailer->Username = $usuario;   
            }
            public function mailPassword($pass){
              $this->oPhpMailer->Password = $pass;       
            }
            public function mailHost($host){
              $this->oPhpMailer->Host = $host;      
            }
            public function mailSubject($subject){
              $this->oPhpMailer->Subject = $subject;       
            }
            public function mailAddress($address){
              $this->oPhpMailer->addAddress($address);     
            }
            public function mailAltBody(){
              $this->oPhpMailer->AltBody = 'This is a plain-text message body';     
            }

            public function mailHtml(){

            }

            public function setData ($usuarios){ 

              $htmlMail = $this->oPhpMailer->msgHTML(file_get_contents('helpers/mailAvisoSinTareasReg/contenido.html'));
              $htmlMailChange = str_replace("TRABAJO","LAZOS",$htmlMail);
              $this->sendMail();
            }


            public function sendMail(){

            if (!$this->oPhpMailer->send()) {
                        echo "Mailer Error: " . $this->oPhpMailer->ErrorInfo;
                    } else {
                        echo "Message sent!";
                    }

            }
    }
?>
```

I have this error :

[image]

I know that the user and pass are ok , so i don't know what is the problem.

How can I fix this? , sorry for my english

Comment: `Learn more at 535 5.7.8 https://support.google.com/mail/answer/14257`? You've looked at this... right?

Comment: ...and the troubleshooting guide on github linked further down.

Answer (score 3):

If you’re receiving the following error:

```
SMTP -> ERROR:Password not accepted from server. Code: 535 Reply: 535-5.7.1 Please log in with your web browser and then try again.
```

Even if the Gmail account credentials are correct, Google’s servers may still block the server attempting to authenticate (more than likely due to a new server location and/or recent password change).

**To get around this,** make sure you are logged in using the same Gmail account in your browser, and then simply open the link below and step through the process of verification:
  https://accounts.google.com/b/0/DisplayUnlockCaptcha

This will allow access to your Gmail account for about 10 minutes so that a new authenticating server can be detected.  Be sure to try authenticating again within this time period."

SRC: http://www.rocketideas.com/2012/05/gmail-error-password-not-accepted-from-server-solved/

---

**TIP:**
You should also take a look at the url (https:/support.google...) presented after the error.

Comment: I agree, the OP didn't research enough because I've found the answer in 1 minute. Copy and Pasting an answer from a different website is not considered a bad practice as long as you mention the source.

Answer (score 2):

Allow less secure apps in google.
https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps

Answer (score 1):

**Error 1: Password Command Failed: 534-5.7.9 Application-Specific Password Required**
Answer:
This happens mostly when SMTP Mail Server Credentials were correct but Application Specific Password was not provided.

**Error 2: SMTP ERROR: Password Command Failed: 535-5.7.8 Username And Password Not Accepted**
Answer:
If you have encountered this error, then this is mostly because the application specific password is incorrect.

GO to Below Link
https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en

Create App Password by Select app (Other) and copy the generated password and paste  this password in place of gmail password.

Answer (score 0):

Allow `less secure app access` for your gmail account